# Can't install linux-headers-4.7 in packages after installing 4.7 kernel Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, macintosh

Due to the fact that it was recommended I upgrade my kernel to resolve wifi connectivity issues on my Macbook pro (Dual booting alongside Mac OS Sierra), I was looking to find the header file, and it shows up in none of the repos I have in sources.list.

I see `linux-headers` files for 3.16 and 4.8, but not 4.7. I looked through Debian's site for the `amd64` package and it's there but when I click on it, it says it "doesn't exist". Keep in mind this is off the backports repo I installed the 4.7 kernel. Should I just upgrade to 4.8 and use those headers?

Wifi chipset is BCM4360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4.7 kernels are no longer available in the Debian repositories (apart from [snapshots](https://snapshots.debian.org)), so yes, the easiest option is to upgrade to 4.8.

If you install the `linux-image-amd64` and `linux-headers-amd64` packages from backports you'll automatically get the latest backported kernel and matching headers:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-{image,headers}-amd64
```

For you wi-fi chipset, enabling the non-free backports repository and then installing the `broadcom-sta-dkms` and `firmware-brcm80211` should provide the appropriate module and firmware.